# Magento 2 Item with the same ID "24" already exists error

Tags: magento2, orders, order-items

I don't know what is going on, but everytime I go to Sales > Orders, I see this error message:

Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "24" already exists.

I accesed to db in order to check if there was an item_id = "24" but there is nothing.

I don't know what could it cause.
This error message came when I created a custom order status on admin panel. Then I tried to delete this order status, but the error is still there, and I cannot do anything on Sales > Order.

The weird thing is that I can see the Invoices and Shipments, but not the Orders.

I have tried this commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

none of this worked.
Please help